# Is there any way to provide secondary level authentication?

Tags: authentication

I have a requirement to provide secondary level of authentication. I have one salesforce user and I distributed it to five of my team members. First they login with Salesforce user name password after that i want to identified which one of them login in salesforce and update the records.

Any help is gratefully accepted!

Comment: I think best solution here will be to buy extra licenses. I dont think that salesforce encourage this use case

Comment: The only way I know you could *kind of* do this is by doing something similar to using a UserPassword flow as you might use in making API requests. @kurunve is right though. If you've got 5 users, use 5 licences. Salesforce is a business like any other and would want to get paid for it's service. Similarly sharing accounts is a huge no-no as far as security is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

This would violate the Master Subscription Agreement, http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf, so do not do it.

> **4.2 Usage Limits.** Services and Content are subject to usage limits, including, for
>   example, the quantities specified in Order Forms and Documentation.
>   Unless otherwise specified, (a) a quantity in an Order Form refers to
>   Users, and the Service or Content may not be accessed by more than
>   that number of Users, (b) a User’s password may not be shared with any
>   other individual,